# How to get individual data from an array that is outside the loop (while) to insert that data into another table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have done the following to be able to get the results outside the loop (while):

```
$date_day = date('Y-m-d');
$stmt = $con->prepare("
SELECT MAX(l.id_logtrama) AS id_logtrama
     , MAX(l.fechaHora) AS fechaHora
     , l.idCliente
     , l.idEquipo
     , MAX(l.statusGlobal) AS statusGlobal
     , COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM logtrama l
  JOIN equipo e
    ON l.idEquipo = e.idEquipo
   AND l.idCliente = e.idCliente
 WHERE DATE(l.fechaHora)=?
 GROUP 
    BY l.idCliente
     , e.idEquipo
");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date_day);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$DataArray = [];
$stmt->bind_result(
    $DataArray['id_logtrama'],
    $DataArray['fechaHora'],
    $DataArray['l.idCliente'],
    $DataArray['l.idEquipo'],
    $DataArray['statusGlobal'],
    $DataArray['total']
);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $row = [];
    foreach ($DataArray as $key => $val) {
        $row[$key] = $val;
    }
    $array[] = $row;
}
print_r($array);
```

As a result, I get the following:

```
Array ( [0] => 
 Array ( [id_logtrama] => 4 
           [fechaHora] => 2021-04-19 22:01:09.059800 
           [l.idCliente] => 20 
           [l.idEquipo] => 1 
           [statusGlobal] => 2 
           [total] => 1 )
        [1] => Array ( 
          [id_logtrama] => 3 
          [fechaHora] => 2021-04-19 22:01:05.520600 
          [l.idCliente] => 20 
          [l.idEquipo] => 8 
          [statusGlobal] => 2 
          [total] => 3 )
 )
```

I need to be able to insert that data into another table for example `alert_notify`:

```
id_notify id_logtrama idCliente idEquipo alert_type count_notify notify_date
    1         4          20        1          2            1       2021-04-19 22:01:09.059800
    2         3          20        8          2            3       2021-04-19 22:01:05.520600
```

How can I achieve that goal?

Comment: You can do an INSERT...SELECT query directly, no need to extract the data into PHP

Comment: It seems implausible to me that you would want the 'max(statusGlobal)' regardless of datetime, but hey, it's your data.

Comment: @Strawberry The `max (statusGlobal)` is the type of alert, 1 yellow, 2 green and 3 red.

Comment: Sure , but if it's red in the morning then it's red in your result, regardless of the value of fechahora

Comment: @Strawberry I think I have other data to update, well then I have to update all except these two columns that if registered no longer change `idCliente, idEquipo`

Comment: @ADyson How can I do a direct select and insert? I thought that without php it was not possible, the truth in mysql I am not very expert: /

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: You can do : `INSERT INTO my_new_table (column_b) SELECT column_a FROM my_old_table;` As mentioned, I doubt that the SELECT you've provided above is the one that you actually want.

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/

Comment: @Strawberry I don't have much knowledge in mysql, but in PHP if a little more, I have managed to insert the data in the new table as follows: `https://ideone.com/FbXcVm` now I have to see how to avoid insert repeated data, if there already exists `idCliente, idEquipo` based on the same date that is updated if it is another date that inserts a new record.

Comment: Yes , but first you need to be clearer about which row you want to keep.

Comment: @Strawberry I already have it clear friend, these two `idCliente, idEquipo` are maintained and, the rest are updated, only in case the date is different, new data is registered, for example if they are data from the same date 2021-04-20 is updated if the date changes, that is, tomorrow 2021-04-21 new data will be recorded.

Comment: @Valentina just to understand better: is it possible that you have data in your `INSERT` statement which have the same `idCliente`, `idEquipo` and `notify_date` that are already in the database? Furthermore, you need to insert new record if you don't have the same triple `idCliente,  idEquipo, notify_date` in the db, otherwise update the other fields of that row. Is this correct?

Comment: @Ma3x If it is correct friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to make a single statement for SELECT and INSERT.
Doing something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO alert_notify AS SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        MAX(l.id_logtrama) AS id_logtrama,
        MAX(l.fechaHora) AS fechaHora,
        l.idCliente,
        l.idEquipo,
        MAX(l.statusGlobal) AS statusGlobal,
        COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM logtrama l
        JOIN equipo e
            ON l.idEquipo=e.idEquipo
            AND l.idCliente=e.idCliente 
    WHERE DATE(l.fechaHora)=?
    GROUP BY l.idCliente, e.idEquipo
) AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'x'
    FROM alert_notify AS an
    WHERE an.idCliente = t.idCliente
    AND an.idEquipo = t.idEquipo
    AND an.notify_date = t.fetchaHora
)
```

In this way only records without a corrispondence for `idCliente, idEquipo, notify_date` on `alert_notify` will be inserted.

PS: Explicit the line `INTO alert_notify AS SELECT *` with the fields list in the correct order, if the order of the defined field in `alert_notify` differs from the order of the fields returned by the SELECT